# JSON over 7k will not validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, validation

If my JSON string is too big, it will not validate in my javascript.
For instance, if the server returns 15 results, it will fail.
If it returns only 10, it will validate.

Here is the failing JSON

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "mls":"20480",
         "address":"518 WALNUT",
         "dbcity":"ALTA",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61414",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Great 1880 farm house with many updates including half circle screened back deck wants TLC. Large above ground pool",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"4",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"6145",
         "address":"1074 Spoden",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"Il",
         "zip":"61401",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"This 3BR 2BA custom Ranch is located in Lawndale Acres. Features include",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"3",
         "baths":"2"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"6146",
         "address":"529 SCOTCH ELM",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61401",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Enticing 3BD 2BA Tri-level home situated on a large",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"3",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"157186",
         "address":"277 WALNUT AVE",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61401",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"2 bedroom 1 bath bungalow. Spacious kitchen with pantry",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"2",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"6148",
         "address":"404 Second",
         "dbcity":"MONM",
         "dbstate":"Il",
         "zip":"61462",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"This 1895 Queen Anne Victorian near Monmouth College has an open staircase",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"4",
         "baths":"2"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"175111",
         "address":"483 KINGS CANYON",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61201",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Coveted 3 BR",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"3",
         "baths":"2"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"20491",
         "address":"306 Austin",
         "dbcity":"ABIN",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61410",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Charming 2BR home with many interior improvements having recently been done.  You have to see this one!  Attached garage.  TMI Home Warranty.",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"2",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"20492",
         "address":"614 DEPOT",
         "dbcity":"ALTA",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61414",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Nice 3 bedroom ranch on crawl",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"3",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"160268",
         "address":"947 Frank St.",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61401",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"This cute and charming 2 bedroom home is immediately available. Move right in or put your special touches to it and make it your own. Some great features to notice are the new roof (2016)",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"2",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"6157",
         "address":"2555 Costa",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61401",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Entertain handsomely in this exhilarating 5BR 4BA 2-story home situated on 2.93 acres. You can find many desirable features including: ADT home security system",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"5",
         "baths":"2"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"20493",
         "address":"432 HOLMES",
         "dbcity":"ONEI",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61467",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Nice ranch home with many updates! New carpet",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"3",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"6158",
         "address":"168 Pleasant",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"Il",
         "zip":"61401",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Quaint 3BR brick bungalow situated on a nice large lot. Enjoy a peaceful night in the enclosed front porch overlooking the quiet street. Inviting features include natural woodwork & hardwood flooring",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"3",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"20494",
         "address":"115 F",
         "dbcity":"ALPH",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61413",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"2BR home on large corner lot w/ newer roof and covered deck.",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"2",
         "baths":"1"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"20495",
         "address":"263 FULTON",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"IL",
         "zip":"61401",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Spacious 4BR 2BA with formal LR & DR",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"4",
         "baths":"2"
      },
      {  
         "mls":"20496",
         "address":"39 Knox Rd 2150N",
         "dbcity":"GALE",
         "dbstate":"Il",
         "zip":"61401",
         "openHouse1":"",
         "openHouse2":"",
         "openHouseAvail":"",
         "listPrice":"0",
         "remarks":"Beautiful fenced-in 5 acres to enjoy family outings and create memories!  Small pond and 3-stall shed for horses or other pets.  Property is being sold ''As Is.''  Please see supplement for additional information.",
         "srcDB":"spi",
         "beds":"2",
         "baths":"1"
      }
   ],
   "counter":15,
   "error":"0"
}
```

which validates when I check it at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I've used much larger JSON string before. What is happening?

My javascript looks like:

```
 $.ajax({    
        url: "../cgi/search.exe",    
        dataType: "json",       
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        error: ajaxError,           
        success: function(json){        
                if(json.error !== "0"){                     
                    alertify.alert("ERROR "+json.error);
                    return;
                }
```

and the function that parses the ajax error is

```
// generic ajax error handler
function ajaxError(request, type, errorThrown) {
    var message = "There was an error with the AJAX request.\n";
    switch (type) {
    case 'timeout':
        message += "The request timed out.";
        break;
    case 'notmodified':
        message += "The request was not modified but was not retrieved from the cache.";
        break;
    case 'parsererror':
        message += "XML/Json format is bad.";      
        break;
    default:
        try{
            message += "HTTP Error (" + request.status + " " + request.statusText + ").";
        }catch(e){
            return;
        }   
    }
    alertify.alert(message);
}
```

Comment: I'm able to parse that json just fine. I'd guess there's some hidden character on one of the later records that's breaking it that got lost in creating the question.

Comment: Did you try hardcoding the string in a file and parsing it? What browsers did you try this in? What is the exact error message you're getting (as I am also unable to reproduce)? Please visit the help center and read about how to ask a question here, including producing a MCVE.

Comment: Seems to be parsing just fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/ds7dewvo/). What's with all the down votes? Can't ask a question nowadays. Like you have to be perfect already. Geez

Comment: Kevin B was correct. There was some invalid data in the string, specifically a chr$(196), which for some reason didn't show when I cut and pasted the json. Thanks for your help. If you want to give an "official" answer, I will give you credit. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saying what kind of error you are getting. So I am guessing:

1. Make sure that your  server response mimetype is  `application/json,` otherwise you might be trying to parse your json as xml... If there is no mimetype, some browsers try to guess it applying heuristics (which might work for small responses, and fail for others)
2. If you are getting an error `alertify.alert("ERROR "+json.error);` then your JSON is being parsed OK. Notice that your JSON has a property

> "error":"0"

This value does not flag an error in the JSON itself. It is application specific. Dependin on how your jQuery uses converts the JSON into a JS object, this value might get converted as string or integer. You are using a strict equility comparasion. To be on the safe side, change

```
if(json.error !== "0"){
```

To

```
if(json.error == 1 (or true or "yes" or whatever signals an error in your application)
```

Comment: The error is coming the $.ajax method, and the error message itself comes from the function ajaxError.  
error="0" is when an error is passed from the server, which is not the same as validating the JSON.

I've narrowed down the issue to this, specific line of text in the JSON

*"5 bedroom ranch w/2 car detached garage. Property is sold ''AS IS'' including any existing appliances"*

I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with that.

Comment: @Shawn can you put that record in your question?  Because if that is verbatim what one of the remarks is, then you have unescaped `"` around AS IS

Comment: I found the error: there was an invalid character in the json string (chr$(196), I'll give Kevin B the credit. thanks